# Error while reading a file from parent directory

Tags: r

I have "A/B/C" and I am working in C directory. I have a file in directory B which references a file from directory A. Let's say file from each directories are "file A", "file B" and "file C" respectively.

```
File C: source("../file B")
File B: source("../file A")
```

Above code gives me an error while below code works fine.

```
File C: source("../file B")
File B: source("../../file A")
```

Now, Issue is other files in directory B also read "File B." Is there any way I can make changes so it works for both level of files?

Comment: Use the `here` package to designate a common root, probably `A/`

Comment: You can consider using `normalizePath` to convert relative paths to absolute.